# Using Java log4j in Mathematica

Tags: java

Someone has a code example of how `log4j` can be used to create logs in Mathematica?

`RLink` uses it, as can be checked in `initLogger[]` function, in this file:

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin@{DirectoryName@DirectoryName@FindFile["RLink`"], "RLink.m"}
```

But it's not a stand alone code. If someone has a simpler one, I would appreciate.

Comment: One username comes to my mind :)

Comment: @belisarius yes... some friend, that as you, has more than 70k points.

Comment: Well, the code in RLink pretty much shows how this can be used. The only missing piece is the logger instance, which is referred there as ``RLinkInit`rlogger``, and for which instead you can use ``Logger`getLogger["YourApp"]``. And you will have to first `LoadJavaClass["org.apache.log4j.Logger"]`, and add the log4j.jar to the classpath.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, interesting. Now I'm a little more comfortable with Java and Mathematica. I'll make some tests. tks

Comment: I will post a minimal code, in a moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Minimal code

Here is a minimal code (partly adopted from RLink), to get you started. First, load JLink:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[]
```

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[logIt];
logIt[logger_,msg_String,mode_String]:=
  Block[{trace, debug, info, warn, error, fatal},
    With[{
      method = mode /. {
        "TRACE" -> trace, 
        "DEBUG" -> debug, 
        "INFO" -> info, 
        "WARN" -> warn, 
        "FATAL" -> fatal,
        _ :> Return[$Failed, Block]
      }},
      JavaBlock@logger@method[JavaNew["java.lang.String", msg]]
    ]
  ];

logIt[logger_,msg_String]:=logIt[logger, msg, "INFO"];
```

And the `initLogger` function:

```
ClearAll[initLogger];
initLogger[logger_, logFile_]:=
  Module[{},        
    logger@removeAllAppenders[];
    logger@addAppender[
      JavaNew["org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"]
    ];
    logger@addAppender[
      JavaNew[
        "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender", 
        JavaNew["org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout"],           
        logFile
      ]
    ];
    logIt[logger, "Logger initialized"];
  ];
```

#### Example of use

Here is an example (I assume that log4j is already on the classpath, which is usually so, because it is used also internally in Mathematica):

```
LoadJavaClass["org.apache.log4j.Logger"]
```

Now create a logger instance:

```
logger = Logger`getLogger["MyApp"]

(* « JavaObject[org.apache.log4j.Logger]» *)
```

and the log file:

```
$logFile = FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "mylog.txt"}];
```

Now, initialize the logger:

```
initLogger[logger, $logFile]
```

You can test:

```
Import[$logFile, "String"]

(* "INFO - Logger initialized" *)
```

Now log something:

```
Do[
  If[i < 5, 
    logIt[logger, "i = " <> ToString [i]], 
    logIt[logger, "fatal error", "FATAL"]; Break[]
  ], 
  {i, 1, 10}
]
```

check:

```
Import[$logFile, "String"]

"INFO - Logger initialized
 INFO - i = 1
 INFO - i = 2
 INFO - i = 3
 INFO - i = 4
 FATAL - fatal error"
```

You can do more interesting things with loggers with log4j, but this example should get you started.

Comment: Tks a lot! Works like a charm! +1

Comment: @Murta Glad to help, as usual. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: @Murta Of course, the real reason why I used log4j in RLink is that I could append to the logger on both Mathematica and Java sides of RLink. If you only need Mathematica - side, you can simply use appending to a file. But for the hybrid Java / Mathematica apps, being able to use one and the same logger for both sides is important. The way you do this is to have a logger be a field of some Java class on the Java side, and then pass that instance to Mathematica. For RLink, the logger is a (static) field of `RLinkInit` class , accessed via ``RLinkInit`rlogger``  in Mathematica.