# How to setup logging levels?

Tags: front-end, debugging

I was wondering what tools exist out there for doing logging in *Mathematica*? The `Echo` functions is nice, but I'd like to set various severity levels and other behaviors.

Comment: A cheap way would've been to use `log4J` via JLink. [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96108/using-java-log4j-in-mathematica) is a relevant discussion.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that